# Subgroups of ${(\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z})}^n$ for $q = p^k$, $p$ is an odd prime

Tags: group-theory, modules

I will denote $\mathbb{Z}_q = \mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}$. Would you know how can be described the submodules of $\mathbb{Z}_q^n$ for $q = p^k$ (here $p$ is an odd prime)?
I didn't find the question for this cases, only some more general ones but I suppose the situation can be easier in the case where $q$ has this form.

**Context:**  I try to understand how the image of a $\mathbb{Z}_q$ module homomorphism $f \colon \mathbb{Z}_q^m \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_q^n$ can be (I want specifically to study the probability that it is surjective for $f$ uniformly taken) and I think it would be interesting to know the structure of $\mathrm{Im}(f)$.

Comment: I presume that by  ${\mathbb Z}_q$ you mean $ {\mathbb Z}/(q{\mathbb Z})$. Isn't your problem equivalent to finding the additive subgroups of  ${\mathbb Z}_q^n$?

Comment: Youre right  thank you, i make an edit.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how helpful this is, but the additive subgroups of ${\mathbb Z}_q^n$ correspond to $n \times n$ matrices $A$ in (Row) Hermite Normal Form for which the row span of $A$ contains $qI_n$. That is true for any positive integer $q$ (and that is how they are computed in Magma for example).

Comment: This is interesting! Do you have a reference that state and prove it?

Comment: Proposition 2.1 of [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0747717100910149)